# Proving Gaussianity of a specific Hilbert-valued random vector

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, statistics, hilbert-spaces, normal-distribution

Let $(X,Y)$ be a zero-mean Gaussian $H$ x $H$-valued random variable, where H is a Hilbert space.

And, let $G'=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{M} l_i(Y)|\;M\in \mathbb{N},l_i\in \mathbb{L}\right\}$ and $G=\bar{G'}$ (the closure in the $L_2^H $ sense), where $\mathbb{L}$ is the collection of bounded linear operators acting on $H.$

Then, I wonder how to show that $(X-\pi(X),Y)$ is also Gaussian, where $\pi$ is the projection of $L_2^H$ onto the subspace $G.$

Also, if possible, I'd like to know what references I could refer to for those kinds of things, that is, properties of function-valued random variables including Gaussianity and so on.